# Jekyll Liquid: Multiple calculations

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'd like to display the previous year in my Jekyll posts. To get the current year, I just use:

```
We are in {{ site.time | date: '%Y' }} today
```

The question is, how do I get the previous year

```
We were in {{ site.time | date: '%Y' - 1 }}
```

That last statement doesn't work, hence the question.

Comment: try `date: %Y - 1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `minus` filter:

```
We were in {{ site.time | date: '%Y' | minus: 1 }}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks matt! Curious though, where'd you find that from? I read the whole [Jekyll page](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/) on this and found no mention of `minus`.

Comment: @FloatingRock it’s one of the [standard Liquid filters](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#standard-filters). Jekyll adds a load more, but this is one of the “built in” ones.